# Use Font Awesome icons in CoreUI sidebar

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, core-ui

I'm trying to replace the default CoreUI icons from the admin panel template sidebar with a Font Awesome icons.

I've installed Font-Awesome successfully using the [latest official installation instructions](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#installation) of FontAwesome for vue and can display the icons just fine using the `<font-awesome-icon icon="tasks" />` syntax. But I can't get the same icon to show up in the CoreUI Sidebar component.

Here is my `_nav.js`:

```
export default [
  {
    _name: 'CSidebarNav',
    _children: [
      {
        _name: 'CSidebarNavItem',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        to: '/dashboard',
        icon: 'cil-speedometer'
      },
      {
        _name: 'CSidebarNavItem',
        name: 'Account',
        to: '/account',
        icon: 'cil-bank'
      },
      {
        _name: 'CSidebarNavItem',
        name: 'Projects',
        to: '/projects',
        fontIcon: 'fas fa-tasks'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So far I tried `fontIcon: 'fas fa-tasks'`, `icon: 'fas fa-tasks'`, `icon: 'faTasks'`, etc. but nothing works.

As you can see below, the "tasks" icon show up in the card body (using `<font-awesome-icon icon="tasks" />`), but not in the sidebar for the *Project* item.
[image: Current Result]

[This link](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/issues/88) suggest using `fontIcon` api instead of `Icon`, however this requires the CSS versions of icons to be imported, which I can't find using the recommended Font Awesome installation guide.

At this point how could I either import the CSS icons so it works with the [`CSidebarNavItem`](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/sidebar.html#csidebarnavitem-api) component, or is there a way to reference a Font Awesome icon directly ?

Answer (score 1):

This is fontawesome icon portal  https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/address-book  . Here icon name has **address-book**. You can't access directly **address-book** name in coreui template.

you should use this **fa** key

> fa fa-address-book

sample code,

```
{
 name: 'Address',
 url: '/address',
 icon: 'fa fa-address-book',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass children `CSidebarNavItem` for custom content (component supports only `CIcon` component configuration by default)

```
 <CSidebarNavItem>
   <CLink
     class="c-sidebar-nav-link"   
     to="/home/test02"
     :exact="true"
     activeClassName="c-active"
   >
     <FontAwesomeIcon class="c-sidebar-nav-icon" icon="faCoffee" />
     Test02
   </CLink>
  </CSidebarNavItem>
```

You have sidebar rendered through CRenderFunction which docs are available here:
https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/render-function.html
Also `CSidebarNavItem` and `CIcon`components are documented on this site

Comment: So I have to replace the default `CSidebarNavItem` template with as custom one like the code above? Any pointer how I can do that (still new to Vue).

Comment: So I managed to register my custom version of the `CSidebarNavItem` component and it works. But would there be a way to do the same with a slot overwrite inside the `CRenderFunction` ?

Comment: Yes, CRenderFunction is just used for rendering component tree.

Answer (score 0):

just add core ui and font Awesome css classes together in i tag

```
{
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
     name: 'Category',
     to: '/category',
     icon: <i class="fad fa-acorn c-sidebar-nav-icon"></i>,
},
```

Comment: this fails... at least in coreui vue 4.0

Comment: please check your Core ui version classes 'c-sidebar-nav-icon' by using inspect elements